# How to delete elements from multidimensional array where sum of values equals 0?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a stack of 32 x 32 grayscale images in a multidimensional array `masks` as follows:

```
(2560, 1, 32, 32)
```

Some of these images contain a non-zero value if I sum their values.

I'd like to remove from the multidimensional array those elements whose sum of values equals zero.

This is how I'm approaching it:

```
for idx in range(masks.shape[0]):
    if np.sum(masks[idx]) == 0:
        masks = np.delete(masks, idx)
```

After the first iteration where a zero-sum element is found, `masks` changes from shape

`(2560, 1, 32, 32)`

to

`(2621439,)`

Why is this happening and how do I resolve it? What I desire is to only reduce the first dimension, e.g.

`(2120, 1, 32, 32)`

Comment: Check the `np.delete` docs. If you do not specify an `axis`, `delete` will operate on the flattened array. Try `masks = np.delete(masks, idx, axis=0)`.

Comment: What did you intend to see after deleting all zero elements?

Comment: @RobertValencia something like `(2120, 1, 32, 32)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a one dimensional array because you didn't provide *axis* parameter for `np.delete`, according to docs:

> If `axis` is None, `obj` is applied to the flattened array.

Besides it's not a good idea to loop through an array while deleting elements, which makes it hard to keep track of the index since the object's size is changing:

For your case:

```
masks = masks[masks.sum(axis=(1,2,3)) != 0]
```

should delete arrays whose sum of all values for axis *1,2,3* is zero.

Comment: This uses boolean indexing; It doesn't modify the original array but returns a new one, you can assign the result back to `masks` if you want it to get overwritten.

Comment: this works -- one issue that I should have mentioned in OP is that I'm using the index of a deleted image in this array to *also delete* a corresponding image on another identically shaped array -- any suggestions?

Comment: Say if the other identically shaped array is *arr*, then similarly you can do `arr[masks.sum(axis=(1,2,3)) != 0]` to delete corresponding elements based on sums from *masks*.

Comment: problem is `masks` is a binarized array and `arr` has values between `(0, 255)` -- what is `0` on `masks` could be a low, non-zero value on `arr` -- and as you pointed out, when looping I'm having trouble with indexing of an object changing in size...

Comment: If `arr.shape == masks.shape` and you want to delete elements in arr where masks.sum is zero. Then the method I suggest should work unless I misunderstand your question, it shouldn't matter what data types they contain. `masks.sum(axis=(1,2,3)) != 0` is a boolean vector which can be applied to any vector with the same length for element selection purpose.

Comment: got it — so if I want to delete the zero-sum image in `masks` **and** the corresponding image in `arr` would this be correct? `arr = arr[masks.sum(axis=(1,2,3)) != 0]` followed by `masks = masks[masks.sum(axis=(1,2,3)) != 0]`

Comment: That would be how I would do it. Even better, you can precalculate the boolean array as `idx = masks.sum(axis=(1,2,3)) != 0; arr = arr[idx]; masks = masks[idx]` to avoid repetitive calculation.